# Calling C methods with Char** arguments from Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, char, ctypes

I need a way to pass an array to char* from Python using ctypes library to a C library.

Some ways I've tried lead me to segmentation faults, others to rubbish info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've been struggling with this issue for some time, I've decided to write a small HowTo so other people can benefit.

Having this C piece of code:

```c
void passPointerArray(int size, char **stringArray) {
  for (int counter=0; counter < size; counter++) {
    printf("String number %d is : %s\n", counter, stringArray[counter]);
  }
}
```

We want to call it from python using ctypes (more info about ctypes can be found in a previous post), so we write down the following code:

```py
def pass_pointer_array():
  string_set = [
    "Hello",
    "Bye Bye",
    "How do you do"
  ]

  string_length = len(string_set)

  select_type = (c_char_p * string_length)
  select = select_type()

  for key, item in enumerate(string_set):
    select[key] = item

  library.passPointerArray.argtypes = [c_int, select_type]
  library.passPointerArray(string_length, select)
```

Now that I read it it appears to be very simple, but I enjoyed a lot finding the proper type to pass to ctypes in order to avoid segmentation faults...

Comment: If the C function modifies the strings, create `c_char` arrays with `create_string_buffer`, e.g. `select = (POINTER(c_char) * len(string_set))(*map(create_string_buffer, string_set))`.

Comment: And which arg type should I use then?

Comment: If type safety isn't a concern you can just use `c_void_p`. That will accept any pointer type. You can also use `POINTER(POINTER(c_char))`. However, the ctypes type system is unforgiving, so if you're mixing in `c_char_p` arrays you'll have to `cast` first to keep it from whining.

Comment: Thanks a lot! didn't think void could be the solution :-)

Comment: The [`from_param` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l1634) of `c_void_p` also accepts Python integers and strings.